# Will I fit or need an extension?(first time flyer)

Tags: air-travel, japan

I am 5'5" tall and weigh 250 lbs. I have never flown before but am flying to visit my son who is in the Navy serving in Japan this month. I will fly American AirlinesExpress to Chicago and then ANA Premium Economy to Japan. I am sick worrying about it.

Do you think I will fit and do you think I will need an extension?

I have lost 80 pounds but still have more to lose. I'm sad I cannot get excited about my trip for worrying about fitting in my seat.

Comment: Phone the airline and find out for sure instead of worrying and getting "maybe" answers from strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry. For example, check http://www.thinnertimesforum.com/topic/54606-q-to-those-that-dont-need-the-seatbelt-extension-in-airplanes/

> I did not need to wear an extension when I flew last time - I am 5'9" and weighed 260ish pounds. I was in an 18-20 size clothes.
>
> last time I flew, I was prob around 300 lbs. (or a bit higher) and I didn't use an extender. Never have actually, and my highest was 330lbs. Size 22 or 24 pants at lane bryant and I'm 5"6.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more concerned about my hips fitting between the armrests, then whether or not I need an extension.

The airline will provide you with an extension for each flight. And there is no shame in using one, but if you are worried about the appearance, you can wear a loose fitting, un-tucked blouse that will cover over the fact you are using the extension while seated.

But the width of the seat is the biggest factor in terms of enjoying your flight.

Comment: The good news is that the ANA premium economy seats are a bit wider than the normal economy seats. The flight to Chicago may be a tight squeeze, but the longhaul flight should be better.